# mount samba share error

Tags: samba, shared-folders

Following this ubuntu [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) doing Mounting password protected network folders and then get an error like this

```
$ sudo mount -a 
mount error(22):Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Can anyone give me some tips?

Here is the fstab file

```
 # /etc/fstab: static file system information.

 #
 # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

 # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

 # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

 #
 # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

 # / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=58b63c7f-9fe8-4422-a571-ebcc726caadc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

 # /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=04efdfed-5243-498f-ad5d-65119168e122 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

 # swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=0ddb7810-bfec-427d-937d-20ba0dbeb738 none            swap    sw              0       0



 #network drive


//192.168.0.10/HomeData /media/homeshare cifs credentials=/home/sean/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sec=ntlm` is what is causing it to throw the error. Just remove that.

At some point between 14.04 and 18.04 pre-beta this argument went away.

Answer (score 0):

Without details, you will need the remote IP of the Windows machine, and the admin username and password for it. Next, you need to make sure you have shared the Windows folder correctly. Right click the folder in question, select Properties, click the Sharing tab, click the Advanced Sharing button, click Share this folder, click Permissions, make sure "Everyone" has full control, if "Everyone" group is not created, do so by adding it, then grant the permissions. Then make sure you've created the `~/.smbcredentials` file with username and password lines filled out. You also need to make sure you have created a mount point in your system `sudo mkdir /mnt/somesharename`. Next, edit the `/etc/fstab` file by adding the following line at the end `//<ip of remote server>/<name of folder on remote server> /mnt/<name of new remote directory> cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`